# How to maintain two different versions of software in github?

Tags: github

Currently, I'm working on a project where we have Basic Version and Premium Version where the premium has more features than basic. Now I want to maintain two different versions of the product in GitHub so that if any bugs comes in Basic or premium can be sorted out. The problem is how to put both version in single repository? If not possible what is alternative for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the software in a single repository, you only have one option, which is to **keep two development branches**. One branch with the standard development and another branch with the premium development.

You can **create these branches** as follows:

```
git checkout -b basic_version
git checkout -b premium_version
```

Once created, you can **move through the different branches** with

```
git checkout basic_version
```

when you want to stay in `basic_version` and

```
git checkout premium_version
```

when you desire the `premium_version`.